# Recombining split string in java for android

Tags: java, android, string

I've been working on an app that will allow the user to select days of the week. Those days will then be sent via an intent to the calendar to pre-populate repeatability of the event however rrule only accepts the first two letters of days of the week. I've been able to split and string and reduce the days of the week to the first two letters but now I need to recombine them to be separated by commas so I can send them in an intent. Here is my code:

```
int durationColumnIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(PrescriptionContract.PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_FREQUENCY_DURATION);
                String duration1 = mCursor.getString(durationColumnIndex);
                String [] duration2 = duration1.split("\\s+");
                for (int x=0; x < duration2.length;x++) {
                    if (duration2[x].length() >= 2) {
                        duration2[x]= duration2[x].substring(0, 2);
                        Log.v("CatalogActivity", duration2[x] + " rows deleted from prescription database");
                    }
                }
```

As you can see I'm at a lost as to how to recombine them. I've tried:

String.join(", ", duration2) but it doesnt seem to work. My goal is to basically turn "Monday Wednesday Sunday" into Mo,We,Su this should be a single string. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Stringbuilder

```
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int durationColumnIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(PrescriptionContract.PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_FREQUENCY_DURATION);
    String duration1 = mCursor.getString(durationColumnIndex);
    String[] duration2 = duration1.split("\\s+");
    for (int x = 0; x < duration2.length; x++) {
        if (duration2[x].length() >= 2) {
            duration2[x] = duration2[x].substring(0, 2);
            stringBuilder.append(duration2[x].substring(0, 2)).append((","));
            Log.v("CatalogActivity", duration2[x] + " rows deleted from prescription database");
        }
    }
    Log.v("CatalogActivity", stringBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this: `String recompined = TextUtils.join(",", duration2);`  
Change `,` to what you like for delimeter.